# [BR:Stream:ErrStreamLogTaskExist]stream task already exists

Tags: tidb

I deployed TiDB in public cloud kubernetes cluster. Everything is okay and running as expected. But when I try to do backup to S3 using BR with log method. [docs](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb-in-kubernetes/stable/backup-to-aws-s3-using-br#log-backup). After that, I want to terminate the backup, but I forget to step by step turn off the job and directly delete backup. After the backup deleted and running a backup again this error occured:
It supports single stream log task currently: [BR:Stream:ErrStreamLogTaskExist]stream task already exists

I have already trying to add logStop: true by editing config directly. I doesn't work. I try another step by delete backup and try to add logStop: true directly when applying config. When I try to see `kubectl describe backup -n backup-test` the logStop state is already true but when I checked `kubectl get backup -n backup-test` the status is empty. I already try all suggestion that have same case in tidb user group forum attached:
https://asktug.com/t/topic/1008335
https://asktug.com/t/topic/997636
But I doesn't work at all the backup still running and can't be stopped

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to use 'br log status' and 'br log stop' commands to stop the task? You can refer to the doc here: https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/br-pitr-manual